# how to call another class's member function?

Tags: c++, class

I have two class, class A, Class B, in class B has a static function like below:

```
class A {
public:
    void method(){ B::method(); }

};

class B {
public:
    static int method() {
        cout << "method of b" << endl;
    
    }
};

int main()
{
    class A a;
    a.method();
}
```

this code build error, because in class A, B is not be declared, but I want class A  be defined earlier than class B, how should i do? I was thought it may need forward declaration, but it seems not this reason...

Comment: Move the body of the function out of the class after `B` has been defined.

Comment: "but I want class A be defined earlier than class B" *Why*? What problem do you hope to solve this way? "I was thought it may need forward declaration, but it seems not this reason..." Why do you think so? How did you try using a forward declaration? What happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the modified code. Inline comments explain the changes:

```
class A { 
public:
    // only declare the method
    void method();
    // Do NOT define it here:
    // { B::method(); }
};

class B { 
public:
    static int method() {
        std::cout << "method of b" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }   
};

// and now, as B implementation is visible, you can use it.
// To do this, you can define the previously declared method:
void A::method() { B::method(); }

int main()
{
    class A a;
    a.method();
}
```

Hint: Please never use `using namespace std`